# QuickFix/n : Tag not defined in order

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to prepare a Quote request using quickFix/n but the tag order is automatically sorted by quickfix/n. Can anyone suggest how can I manually specify tag orders in my application?

Below is the message that is automatically sorted by quickfix/n:

```
8=FIX.4.2
9=207
35=R
34=20
49=XXXXXXXXXX
52=20140822-21:38:13.632
56=XXXXXXX
131=041053e4-45c2-4287-8662-dbe8193adf42
146=1
55=AUD/CHF
1=fixrfq
15=CHF
38=10000
6365=150
6366=RFQ_SINGLE_QUOTE_STREAM
6368=SPOT
10=237
```

Below is the actual message which I want to construct:

```
8=FIX.4.2
9=207
35=R
49=XXXXXX
56=XXXXXXXXS
34=20
52=20140822-21:38:13.632
131=041053e4-45c2-4287-8662-dbe8193adf42
146=1
55=AUD/CHF
38=10000
15=CHF
6368=SPOT
1=fixrfq
6365=150
6366=RFQ_SINGLE_QUOTE_STREAM
10=237
```

Is it possible to add fields to a message in a specific order?

Comment: Please edit your question to add visible field separators to the messages, then I'm sure I can help you.

Comment: `define message tags in specific order`, what is the need to do this ? It will be a burden, to sort them or keep them in order which will add time to your processing, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: FIX protocol does not impose an ordering except for repeating groups. As a result, you should not care at all about the order of the fields (except for those in repeating groups).

Comment: Maybe a (bad) client is requesting this.